# Стилизация аудиоплеера

Tags: javascript, html, аудио, плагин

Подскажите, каким вы плагином пользуетесь для стилизации аудиоплеера? А то я пользуюсь auidioplayer'ом и при его использовании на странице выдаются какие-то непонятные ошибки, а они ненужны

Comment: А что за ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Имеется такая подборка: [12 ПРЕМИУМ АУДИО ПЛЕЕРОВ НА HTML5](https://postovoy.net/12-luchshih-audio-pleerov-na-html5.html). Но они платные, а за бесплатно можно стилизовать вручную с помощью видимых элементов страницы - **div** и т. п. Главное, чтобы у аудиоплеера атрибут **controls** был в состоянии **false**, иначе будет видна родная панель с кнопками.